# Heroku app crash : heroku[router]: at=error code=H10

Tags: heroku

I just started a new app on heroku, I used `git clone` from a running application. I pushed everything up, migrated the db, and restarted heroku. The app still crashes.
`heroku logs` gives me:

`2014-02-27T01:18:25.726069+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=********.herokuapp.com request_id=1ded5a34-7d01-440b-9fb4-0041fdc64715 fwd="75.149.130.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=`

`code=H10` is an "app or dyno crash". The app is running on Thin if that helps.

How do I restart dynos? What can I do to get some more diagnostic info on this?

edit: (more info)

I ran `heroku restart thin` and immediately ran `heroku logs` which uncovered this:
`ruby: symbol lookup error: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/rubyeventmachine.so: undefined symbol: rb_enable_interrupt`

The app is built on ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.10 so I would assume there is some kind of version issue going on here, but I don't understand it.
[This article](http://platypus.belighted.com/blog/2013/01/21/ruby-2-rails-4-heroku/) mentions the same problem with Thin, and recomends not using it. But I have the EXACT same app running fine as another heroku app, and all I've ever used is thin, I really have no idea why this isn't working.

edit 2:

It looks like although my app is built with ruby 1.9.2, heroku is trying to deploy it with ruby 2.0.0. How do I tell it to use 1.9.2? Something in set-up or in my gem/config files?

edit 3: (I think I'm on to something)

running `ruby -v` yields 1.9.2

running `heroku run "ruby -v" yields 2.0.0

[This article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) says it can be declared in the gemfile. I have a feeling this will fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku ruby buildpack will install the ruby version specified in your Gemfile. Ruby 2.0.0 is the current default ruby.

To configure Ruby 1.9.2 as the version needed for your app, add the following to the top of your Gemfile:

```
ruby '1.9.2'
```